# React Native - Can't render my component when new message incoming in socket

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, rendering

My client side is in React Native (android app).
In my chat feature, the client listening to websocket event that alerts when new message incoming in the chat. When I get the message from the socket, I render the specific chat message component.
In emulator everything work just fine and the component is rendering. When we install the APK on our devices, the chat doesn't render.
I thought maybe there are disconnections from the socket, but it's stable, what can be the problem?

This is how I listening to the websocket message:

```
function socketService(token) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(`${path}`, null, {
      headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    });

    if (socket) {
      socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('SOCKET CONNECTED');
      };
      socket.onmessage = event => {
          console.log('New message');
          return emitter({type: newMessageWaiting.type, payload: event.data});
        }
      };
      socket.onclose = event => {
        console.log(event);
        alert('SOCKET CLOSED');
      };
    }
    return () => {
      console.log('SOCKET OFF');
    };
  });
}

export function* watchSocket() {
  const token = yield select(getToken);
  const requestChan = yield call(socketService, token);

  try {
    while (true) {
      let data = yield take(requestChan);
      if (data.type === refreshOnlineUsers.type) {
        yield put(refreshOnlineUsers());
      }
      if (data.type === newMessageWaiting.type) {
        let theirMessage = JSON.parse(data.payload);
        yield put(newMessageWaiting());
        yield put(addMessageToChat({myMessage: theirMessage}));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

This is how I render the chat component:

```
const messageWaiting = useSelector(state => state.chat.messageWaiting);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getMessages = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${path}/chats/${myId}/${friendId}/0`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + verifyToken,
        },
      });
      if (res.data.hasOwnProperty('msg')) {
        dispatch(
          setCurrentChat({
            currChat: [],
          }),
        );
      } else {
        dispatch(
          setCurrentChat({
            currChat: res.data,
          }),
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    alert('**1*');
    getMessages();
    alert('**2*');
  }, [dispatch, messageWaiting]); //BUG - NOT RENDER ON-NEW-MESSAGE
```

Comment: Do you use https?